# jQuery function can't access global scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

Can't find the answer to this particular question.
I have the following:

**index.html**

```
<input class="btn btn-primary btn-md" type="button" value="check">
```

**script.js**

```
var inc = 0;

$("input[type='button']").click(function() {
    console.log('pressed');
    console.log(inc);
    var inc = inc + 1; 
})
```

The **console** logs:

```
pressed 
NaN
```

I thought functions have access to global scope, *inc* was declared in the global scope, hence *0* should be logged.

Comment: Are you sure that the variable in the global scope really still has the value `0`? This looks like something else is overwriting it. You definitely are accessing it, if it was not in scope you'd get a reference error (or `undefined` in sloppy mode), but not `NaN`.

Comment: It seems to see it. Because it return NaN. if it would not know of that var, it would give undefined.

Comment: `NaN` means Not a Number. There is no reason for it to print NaN if you just do `console.log(inc)` in the code you posted. It should print a value or `Undefined`. Please show some code so this can be reproduced.

Comment: Remove the `var` keyword inside your function, because it redefines it locally. http://jsfiddle.net/d9xcvzw9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of `variable hoisting`. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Basically the new `var` inside the anonymous function is hoisted to the top of the function, creating a new `var inc`.

This new variable has no value, so inc + 1 becomes undefined + 1 which is `NAN`.

To fix this all you need to do is remove the `var` keyword from inside the function, this will make the `inc` variable name refer to the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

Now I see that I shouldn't use *var inc* in the function since it was already used in the global scope.